# Is querying MongoDB faster than Redis?

Tags: mongodb, caching, redis

I have some data stored in a database (MongoDB) and in distributed cache redis.

While querying to the repository, I am using lazy loading approach which first finds the data in the cache if it's available, if not find it in the database and update the cache as well so that next time when the requirement comes it should be found in the cache.

Sample Model Used:

```
Person ( id, name, age, address (Reference))
Address (id, place)
PersonCacheModel extends Person with addressId.
```

I am not storing parent object with child object together in the cache that is why I've created personCacheModel with `addressId` and store this object in the cache and while getting the data personCacheModel converts to person and make a call to address repo to `addressCache` to fill the address details of the person object.

As far as I understand:

personRepository.findPersonByName(NAME + randomNumber);

> Access Data from Cache = network time + cache access time + deserialize time
>
> Access Data from database = network time + database query time + object mapping time

When I ran above approach for 1000 rows, accessing data from the database is faster than the accessing data from the cache. I believe cache access time must be smaller than the accessing MongoDB.

Please let me know if there's an issue with the approach or is this is the expected scenario.

Comment: are those 1000 records retrieved in random order or sequence?

Comment: @profesor79 updated, I am getting them in random order but how does it effect the accessing time ? is mongoDB faster than redis caching for this scenario ? I am also converting objects for the repo,  does that adding any cost ??

Comment: See this comparison: http://db-engines.com/en/system/MongoDB%3BRedis

Answer (score 0):

to have a valid benchmark we need to consider hardware side and data processing side:

1. **hardware** - do we have same configuration, RAM, CPUs count, OS... etc
2. **process** - how data is transformed (on single thread, multi thread, per object, per request)

Performing a load test on your data set will give you an good overview of which process is faster in particular use case scenario.

It is hard to judge - what it should be as long as there mentioned above points will be know for us.
The other thing is to have more than one test scenario and have it stressed in let's say 10 sec time, minute , 5 an hour... so you can have digits that will tell you the truth.